# Why is_checkout() conditional tag return true for different WooCommerce pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use `is_checkout()` as condition to filter some value on page in WooCommerce.

However, `is_checkout()` returns true for multiple pages i.e  `get_checkout_order_received_url()` url and others.

Answer (score 4):

When using `is_checkout()`, it returns `true` on checkout page, Order Received (thankyou) page and order pay page, because they all belongs to checkout page, but Order Received and Order Pay pages uses specific endpoints.

To target only checkout page use:

```
if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
    // do something
}
```

To target only Order Received (thankyou) page:

```
if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
    // do something
}
```

To target only Order Pay page:

```
if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay') ) {
    // do something
}
```

Related: [WooCommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: currently i'm using the following condition (not sure if its robust):

$current_url = home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
is_checkout() && strpos(strval($current_url), "wc-ajax=update_order_review") !== false

to detect when the user is on the checkout page. the is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay') differs from checkout.

i added to question update as well.

Comment: i have tried that condition and it is truthy at "checkout/order-received" as well. for further clarification i'm trying to change payment gateway title an using this condition in a addfilter hook "woocommerce_gateway_title"

Comment: @jasan No sorry, I am a developer and I use it everywhere on my plugins and code… That only target checkout page, but not Order received or Order pay pages *(as both uses endpoints)*.

Comment: i am fairly new to woocommerce development, so there may be something i'm doing incorrectly. but that is the current behavior i'm seeing. is there a easy way to share a working WP snippet?

Comment: Did you look at [WooCommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-11) official documentation and specially to `is_wc_endpoint_url()` that can also be used by defining an endpoint. So `if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {` always work on frontend for checkout page.

Comment: Yes I have. This behavior I'm seeing conflicts The woocommerce docs. Very odd indeed.